# Vector/line from polar coordinates

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib

How can i draw a vector/line starting from polar coordinates (magnitude and angle) instead of rectangular coordinates (x, y) in python with matplotlib? I started learning python just a couple days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Translate polar co-ordinates to cartesian co-ordinates by doing the following:

```
x = magnitude*cos(angle)
y = magnitude*sin(angle)
```

Note: Double check if you are using degrees or radians. Usually cos and sin expect radians. To translate from angle to radians, multiply by `(2*pi)/360`. To translate from radians to angle, multiply by `360/(2*pi)`.

Comment: Better yet, use numpy.rad2deg and numpy.deg2rad.